# Is there a way to add a house rule that bypasses all restrictions in PCGEN?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, house-rules, tools, pcgen

I have some house rules that I want to implement, like allowing more than 1 drawback and giving free evolution points to summoners. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to just bypass the built in restrictions.

I would like the program to allow me to do/add what I want, but only warn me when I'm over the limit rather than restrict me.

I'd like to get the warnings, have text in red, but still be able to add things despite being unqualified.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there is no such option available in PCGen. There are a few houserules for turning on or off some restrictions, but nothing to wholesale turn off all restrictions and validations.

Comment: Okay, well instead of bypassing all restrictions. There is already an option to ignore trait restrictions. Is there also a way to ignore drawback restictions or allow more than one drawback?

I thought there was a way to create rules. But I am not good at programming.

By the way, I discovered that you can alter the number of available points of feats, traits, etc by typing in that section on the bottom left where it indicated "total points" and "available points". That was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Most character generations tools already struggle to include all possible options from the core rules, advanced rules and additional material. It would be impossible to accomodate all house rule options in standardized character generation tools.

The pragmatic approach is to create a character to match your needs as closely as possible and than revise the intermediate character sheet with whatever houserules you want to apply. For example, I used a slightly modified way to roll hitpoints, so I created a whole character sheet with an online tool and just recalculated those separately.